# Do While Questions

Tags: java, string, while-loop, do-while

Ok, I'm taking a Comp. Prog. class at my high school and the teacher that "teaches" the class knows practically nothing about programming. I joined the Java UIL team and am teaching the class with curriculum from some college website. Anyways, I started writing a Body Mass Index Calculator yesterday, and have had success but my problem is that I want to have a `println` prompt to run the program again after the calculations have been completed. Now, I have learned the `Do While` loop for this occasion, but my problem is with the scanner. I want to receive input as a string but when I do

```
String a = sc.nextLine();
```

outside of the `do`, it says that `y` or `yes`, cannot be resolved to a variable. A friend suggested `switch cases`, what do you think? I use Eclipse BTW.

```
String a = sc.nextLine();
do{
    wow(); //My method name
}while(a == y); //Error is here
```

Comment: your test should be `a.equals("y")` don't use `==` with strings see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java

Comment: Have you declared `a` and `y`?

Comment: You might need `while("Y".equalsIgnoreCase(a) || "YES".equalsIgnoreCase(a))`

Answer (score 0):

To compare objects in java use .equals() method instead of "==" operator

Use `while(a.equals("y"));` instead of `while(a == y);`

Answer (score 0):

```
while(a == y);
```

This will never work for two reasons:

- `==` compares references, not the contents of the object. So here it is only checking that `a` and `y` point to the same object, not that they contain the same thing.
- You have not declared `y` anywhere. I'm assuming that you want to compare `a` against the literal string `"y"`, in which case you should be using `a.equals("y")`.

Your loop can be structured like this:

```
String input;
do {
    wow();
    input = scanner.nextLine();
} while(input.equalsIgnoreCase("y"));  //using equalsIgnoreCase because user
                                       //can input "y" or "Y".
```